# Printing end match only if there was a beginning match

Tags: awk

I have the following `awk` file.  The problem is that when there is a match for `$0 ~ end_ere` the line gets printed.  But what I want is that the line is printed only when there was previously a match for `$0 ~ beg_ere`.  What can I do?

`beg_ere` matches the beginning of a section, whereas
`end_ere` matches the end of a section.

`pn_ere` removes the comment characters at the beginning of the line.

If `showpr` is true, the lines matching `beg_ere` and
`end_ere` are printed.  Otherwise, only the lines within the section lines are printed (meaning that the lines matching `beg_ere` and `end_ere` are not printed).

```
$0 ~ beg_ere {
   display = 1
   if ( ! showpr ) { next }
 }

$0 ~ end_ere {
   if (( display == 1 )); then
     if ( ! showpr ) { print "" }
     else { sub(pn_ere, "") ; print ; print "" }
   fi
   display = 0
 }

display { sub(pn_ere, "") ; print }
```

Comment: How do you run this script? What are `beg_ere`, `end_ere`, `pn_ere` and why is `showpr` never set? What is your input data, what is your output and what is the expected output? Explain what works so far and what doesn't. You can't expect from the users of this site to read through all of your previous questions to answer this one.

Comment: You don't need to read previous questions.  The task is to print line matching `end_ere` only if there was a match with `beg_ere` first.

Comment: I doubt this code runs at all given that it's a mix of `bash` shell code and `awk`.  The `awk` language does not have `(( ... ))` as a special arithmetic evaluation context, nor does it use `then` or `fi`.

Comment: This is where I started getting things wrong.  Tried to see if display was changed to `1` after a match with `beg_ere`.

Comment: It did not give an error and still run.  I have now changed to `if ( display == 1 ) { }`.

Comment: @Kusalananda  However, `if (( display == 1 ))` is perfectly valid in awk: it just wraps the condition in (unnecessary) single brackets. `if ((((( display == 1 )))))` is good too -- in fact, I like its visibility.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant But in this case it's shell syntax, given the rest of the if-statement.

Comment: I wonder one thing,  if there is a match for `$0 ~ beg_ere`, will the `display` condition still be executed?

Comment: For the last time, PLEASE post a minimal working script and concise, testable sample input and expected output when asking questions so we can best help you can don't waste a lot of time trying to figure out exactly what your question is about. See [ask].

Comment: @Kusalananda you're 100% right, the OP is trying to use shell syntax in their ask script BUT the code would still run, it just means something completely different from what they intended it to mean (an `if` with no associated action and 2 unset variables `then` and `if` just sitting in the code doing nothing). Avacha when someone points out a bug in the code in your question, don't add a comment saying you fixed it - actually fix the code in your question so we don't waste any more time thinking about it and trying to help you debug the wrong code.

Comment: I thought one should not change the original question.

Comment: Aside from adding clarifications, one should not change the requirements in the original question (i.e. don't turn it into a different question) after one has answers, but one should definitely fix any issues pointed out in the comments if one still has the problem after that fix is applied or delete the question otherwise. And one should not add additional information in comments where it can't be formatted and could be missed - all information should be in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it sounds like this is what you're trying to do:

```
$0 ~ beg_ere {
    inBlock = 1
}

inBlock {
    lines[++numLines] = $0
    if ( $0 ~ end_ere ) {
        delta = ( showpwr ? 0 : 1 )
        for ( lineNr=(1+delta); lineNr<=(numLines-delta); lineNr++ ) {
            sub(pn_ere, "", lines[lineNr])
            print lines[lineNr]
        }
        inBlock = numLines = 0
    }
}
```

but obviously I couldn't test it as you didn't provide any sample input/output in your question and the code in your question isn't a minimal, complete script that could be executed.