# Constructing patterns in an awk file

Tags: awk

I am constructing the patterns `pn_ere`, `beg_ere`, and `end_ere` in a bash script that ultimately are used inside an awk script.  I would like to construct the pattern inside the awk script with the user being able to supply values for `faml` and `asmb` , rather than passing the complete `pn_ere`, `beg_ere`, and `end_ere`.  How can I do this change?

```
  nfaml=${faml:-"[[:graph:]]+"}  # Use GPH if FAML null ("" or '')
  nasmb=${asmb:-"[[:graph:]]+"}  # Use GPH if ASMB null ("" or '')
  kw=".*"

  ## Pattern pn_ere matches comment characters.  ## ;; !! @c //
  local pn_ere="^[[:space:]]*([#;!]+|@c|//)[[:space:]]+"

  beg_ere="${pn_ere}(${nfaml}) ${ebl}(${nasmb})${ebr}${spc}(${kw})$"
  end_ere="${pn_ere}END OF ${nfaml} ${ebl}${nasmb}${ebr}${spc}$"

  awk -f "${trk}"/densel -v pn_ere="$pn_ere"  \
      -v beg_ere="$beg_ere" -v end_ere="$end_ere"  \
      "$filename"
```

Comment: The variables are just strings. You can manipulate them any way you want inside your `awk` code. Once you have arrived at the values in your `awk` variables that you want to use as regular expressions, you may use them as shown in this other question:  [Printing end match only if there was a beginning match](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/734646).

Comment: I could construct them in a `BEGIN` clause.  Do the pattern strings require changing inside awk?  How does one put strings next to each other as I am doing with `bash`?

Comment: @Enver see [String Concatenation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-concatenating)

Comment: Perhaps I could use `sprintf` ?

Comment: Please don't multi-post - [constructing-patterns-far-use-in-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75549981/constructing-patterns-far-use-in-awk-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do (untested)?

```
nfaml=${faml:-"[[:graph:]]+"}  # Use GPH if FAML null ("" or '')
nasmb=${asmb:-"[[:graph:]]+"}  # Use GPH if ASMB null ("" or '')
kw='.*'

awk -v nfaml="$nfaml" -v nasmb="$nasmb" -v kw="$kw" '
  BEGIN {
    ebl = "foo"
    ebr = "bar"
    spc = "whatever"

    ## Pattern pn_ere matches comment characters.  ## ;; !! @c //
    pn_ere = "^[[:space:]]*([#;!]+|@c|//)[[:space:]]+"

    beg_ere = sprintf("%s(%s) %s(%s)%s%s(%s)$", pn_ere, nfaml, ebl, nasmb, ebr, spc, kw)
    end_ere = sprintf("%sEND OF %s %s%s%s%s$", pn_ere, nfaml, ebl, nasmb, ebr, spc)
  }

  <... rest of script using the above ...>
' "$filename"
```

You could alternatively set beg_ere and end_ere with just concatenation, e.g.:

```
beg_ere = pn_ere "(" nfaml ") " ebl "(" nasmb ")" ebr spc "(" kw ")$"
```

but IMHO it's cleaner/simpler to separate the format from the data by using `sprintf()` when the string is long.